# UBuntu 12.04 LTS - warnings treated as errors when building Thrift 0.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, thrift

I use UBuntu 12.04 LTS and gcc 4.8.1. I want to build and install Thrift 0.9.1. First I run `./configure`, next `make`, but then I get an information that warnings (unused variables) are treated as errors. I don't want to modify Thrift source code so I need disable that gcc feature, but a Makefile doesn't contain any **-Werror** flag. How to fix that ?

Comment: Can we please get the entire error message (copy+paste)? There are indeed multiple makefiles, some containing -Werror

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build thrift 0.9.1 with GCC 4.8 on my Ubuntu 12.04, too. I didn't get any unused variables warnings treated as errors, but did get unused local typedefs warnings failing the build. I guess this is the same situation you ran into.

In GCC 4.8, `-WAll` enables a new type of warning: `-Werror=unused-local-typedefs` as default. Passing `-Wno-unused-local-typedefs` when configuring should solve your problem:

```
CPPFLAGS=-Wno-unused-local-typedefs ./configure --without-tests
```

Note that I passed as `CPPFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`. The build script of thrift 0.9.1 somehow fails to pass CFLAGS to the Makefile under c_glib directory, while CPPFLAGS did.

Also, the 0.9.1 source tarball was released with compiling problem on some tests. That's why I also included `--without-tests` option.